# Почему никто не стилизирует скролбар?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Почему почти ни один крупный сайт не проводит стилизацию главного скролбара?
Только недавно это заметил и стал на каждом сайте, на который захожу, отмечать наличие стилей у скролла.
Я понимаю, что кросбраузерность такая себе, и что это всё на вкус и цвет, но почему вот вообще 99% сайтов не занимаются этим хотя бы для тех браузеров, где это работает?

Comment: Помнится, такого рода стилизация была довольно массовая в момент появления этой фичи. Даже Гугл в свое время этим баловался для некоторых своих сервисов (уже не вспомню где видел). Потом мода видимо прошла и большинство вернулось к стандартному лаконичному скролу.

Comment: наверное потому что это плохо поддерживается браузерами

Comment: А слабая она как раз потому что никому и не нужна. И мне это непонятно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Последнее время все стремятся к минимализму. Чем меньше элементов на странице тем лучше. Ну и конечно же, чем проще сами элементы тем лучше. 
Еще лет ~10 назад, даже крупные сайты выглядели слишком пёстро и "резали" глаз.
Вот например Яндекс. Вспомните, как выглядела поисковая строка.
[image: 1]
И сравните с тем, как она выглядит сейчас.
[image: 2]
Тоже самое произошло и со скроллбарами. Чем проще тем лучше, верно? А что может быть проще, чем стандартный скролл браузера? :)

Для примера, можете взглянуть на то, как менялся скролл на Mac OS.
[image: 3]

Как мне кажется все эти изменения пошли сайтам на пользу. Давайте посмотрим еще немного картинок и вспомним как раньше выглядели сайты в целом.
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

И взгляните, до чего дошел дизайн уже в наше время.
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

Исходя из всего этого, можно подумать, что использование стандартных скроллов выглядит вполне уместно.

А стилизации скроллбаров сейчас используют для мини окон на сайтах и в этом контексте стандартный скролл выглядит некрасиво, ибо находится он "внутри" сайта.
Вот тут вы можете взглянуть на варианты стилизации скроллбара для окон.
[ссылка](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html)

Comment: В 2011 скролбар у мака куда попроще был :D Я понял, спасибо)